# Insert into select Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have the following code and it give me an error when the table `@ListaDeProducto` has more than 1 row. Any idea?

```
insert into Solicitud_Plastico_Interna_Detalle(
              IDSolicitud_Plastico_Interna
              ,IDTipo_Producto
              ,Cantidad_Solicitada
              ,Create_User
              ,Create_Date
              ,Contingencia
              ,Total
  )
select 
  @IdSolicitud
  ,IDTipo_Producto
  ,Cantidad_Requerida
  ,@USUARIO 
  ,getdate()
  ,Contingencia
  ,Total
from @ListaDeProducto
```

**Table schema**

```
CREATE TYPE [ListaProductoTableType2] AS TABLE 
(
IDTipo_Producto int, 
Tipo_Producto varchar(1000),
Cantidad_Requerida int, 
Contingencia int ,
Total int,
IdSolicitud_batch varchar(100) 
) 
GO
```

Comment: Probably a buggy insert trigger on the table.

Comment: You probably have a trigger for inaert on the table, that is written wrong. Triggers work per statement, not per row. This means that the inserted table can hold multiple rows

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: I get this error;
{"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Line 89"}

Comment: Then Martin give you a nice tip, check for triggers related to `Solicitud_Plastico_Interna_Detalle`

Comment: I have not any trigger in the database. Is important to say that i'm calling a procedure from a .NET application and this procedure among other thing has this code,

Comment: What is the primary key ?. It looks to me that you may be duplicating it.

Comment: I thing that's correct @MarcGuillot, the @@ListaDeProducto  type has not primary key. Thank u.

Comment: It seems this piece of code are executed within a SP, please add the whole code.

Comment: what's inside your @ListaDeProducto?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn this:

CREATE TYPE [ListaProductoTableType2] AS TABLE   
( 
IDTipo_Producto int, Tipo_Producto varchar(1000),Cantidad_Requerida int, Contingencia int ,Total int,IdSolicitud_batch varchar(100)
)
GO

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero this is table schema, I mean the whole code where you use the INSERT.

Comment: Since you don't have a subquery and you say in the comments you don't have any triggers,  in the code you gave us, I suspect you are looking at the wrong part of the code for the error.

Comment: That was correct @HLGEM.

Answer (score 0):

I still will bet there is some trigger in the table.

So why you dont try create a new table to prove this query is ok with multiple rows

```
CREATE TABLE Solicitud_Plastico_Temporal AS (              
    select 
      @IdSolicitud as IDSolicitud_Plastico_Interna
      ,IDTipo_Producto
      ,Cantidad_Requerida
      ,@USUARIO as Create_User
      ,getdate() as Create_Date
      ,Contingencia
      ,Total
    from @ListaDeProducto
)
```